# I can't reload the Captcha of my contact form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii

I'm creating my web page using Yii. When I created the page, Yii created a form very similar than the following:

```
<?php
/* @var $this SiteController */
/* @var $model ContactForm */
/* @var $form CActiveForm */

$this->pageTitle=Yii::app()->name . ' - Contact';
$this->breadcrumbs=array(
'Contact',
);
?>

<?php if(Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('contact')): ?>

<div class="flash-success">
    <?php echo Yii::app()->user->getFlash('contact'); ?>
</div>

<?php else: ?>

<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'contact-form',
'enableClientValidation'=>true,
'clientOptions'=>array(
    'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
),
)); ?>

<p class="note"><?php echo Yii::t('app','Fields with');?> <span class="required">*</span> <?php echo Yii::t('app','are required.');?></p>

<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'name'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'name'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'name'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'email'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'email'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'email'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'subject'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'subject',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>128)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'subject'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'body'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'body',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'body'); ?>
</div>

<?php if(CCaptcha::checkRequirements()): ?>
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'verifyCode'); ?>
    <div>
    <?php $this->widget('CCaptcha'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'verifyCode'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="hint"><?php echo Yii::t('app','Please enter the letters as they are shown in the image above.');?>
    <br/><?php echo Yii::t('app','Letters are not case-sensitive.');?></div>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'verifyCode'); ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit'); ?>
</div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

In the begining, this form worked, but after that, I improved the web page adding more features. Few minutes ago, I was checking all the page and I saw that the reloaded captcha button didn't work. Now, When I try to reload the captcha, the web page is reloaded and display a empty page with this code:

```
{"hash1":774,"hash2":774,"url":"\/MyApp\/site\/captcha.html?v=526045d3d1187"}
```

I tried to search for some similar error in google, but I didn't find anything. To be honest, I don't understand what is happening. I guess that the code that I added in another file of my web page produce this error, but I don't have any idea...I don't understand what means this code.

Please, I need your help!

Someone could help me? THANKS

**EDIT:**

If I look the source code of the web page on my browser, and I search for "captcha.html", I can see the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
jQuery(function($) {
jQuery('#yw0').after("<a id=\"yw0_button\" href=\"\/MyApp\/site\/captcha.html?refresh=1    \">Obtenga un nuevo c\u00f3digo<\/a>");
jQuery(document).on('click', '#yw0_button', function(){
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "\/MyApp\/site\/captcha.html?refresh=1",
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        jQuery('#yw0').attr('src', data['url']);
        jQuery('body').data('captcha.hash', [data['hash1'], data['hash2']]);
    }
});
return false;
});
```

But I didn't find the captcha.html in any place...

**EDIT 2:**
I found the problem. I added javascript code at the end of the main page of my wep page. I added this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl; ?>/scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl; ?>/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl; ?>/scripts/jquery-photostack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl; ?>/scripts/jquery-coin-slider.min.js"></script>
```

If I remove this code, the captcha can be reload correctly. Please, someone could tell me what I'm doing badly here? Why my javascript code produce this? How can I solve it?

Comment: Food for thought: "Always work with incremental copies of your works", that way you can revert to something that used to work. Now, I noticed `captcha.html` - if there is any PHP inside that file and that you haven't properly set Apache to treat `.html` as PHP? If that's the case, then that will stop it right in its tracks.

Comment: Thanks Fredd -ii-, I don't know where is the file captcha.html, I tried to find it but I couldn't....so I am sure that I didn't introduce any php code there...I always try to revise all when I make a change, but to tell you the truth I didn't revise this button and now I don't know what is the problem...

Comment: You're welcome. Well try and see if you can find it. That is very bizarre, having it created by `Yii` but not saved anywhere.

Comment: Fred -ii, I seached for it again but I didn't find it either. I wrote more things in the main post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is [this code](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.14/framework/web/widgets/captcha/CCaptcha.php#L139) in CCaptcha Yii widget:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '$selector', function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
    ...
    });
    return false;
});
```

The click listener is on document, instead of the element itself. When you add your script tags after this code, you load a new jQuery version that clears all those listeners on init.

To solve this, use only one jQuery version, preferably Yii included one.

If you really want to replace it, do it the right way, in `CClientScript->scriptMap` in config, set the value of `jquery.js` and `jquery.min.js` keys to the new URL of jQuery.